# unable set my background image in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, imagebackground

I am new to react native, while learning from native docs , I got stuck by ImageBackground usage. My code is given below , help will be appreciated . It was working fine, but when I started using navigator function, its not working as normal.please suggest an optimal solution to solve this problem.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={{
            uri:
              'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524338198850-8a2ff63aaceb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=358&q=80',
          }}
          style={styles.backgroundContainer}/>
          <Text style={styles.welcomenote}>WELCOME TO ME</Text>
          <View style={styles.loginbtn}>
            <Button style={styles.loginbtn} title="LOGIN" />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.signupbtn}>
            <Button title="SIGNUP" />
          </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  backgroundContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 300,
    height: 100,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center,',
  },
  loginbtn: {
    padding: 20,
    width: '90%',
    height: 40,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 20,
    right: 0,
    top: 250,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  signupbtn: {
    padding: 20,
    width: '90%',
    height: 40,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 20,
    right: 0,
    top: 200,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  welcomenote: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 70,
    right: 0,
    top: 200,
    bottom: 0,
    width: '90%',
    height: 40,
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

everything is fine,it's not showing the background image

Comment: do you want background image to take full height?

Comment: @sachin did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
    import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
    import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

    class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
         <Image source={require('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524338198850-8a2ff63aaceb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=358&q=80')}  style= 
         {styles.backgroundContainer}/>
              <Text style={styles.welcomenote}>WELCOME TO ME</Text>
              <View style={styles.loginbtn}>
                <Button style={styles.loginbtn} title="LOGIN" />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.signupbtn}>
                <Button title="SIGNUP" />
              </View>

          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Details Screen</Text>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Home: HomeScreen,
        Details: DetailsScreen,
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'Home',
      }
    );

    const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return <AppContainer />;
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
      backgroundContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        width: 300,
        height: 100,
        resizeMode: 'cover',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center,',
      },
      loginbtn: {
        padding: 20,
        width: '90%',
        height: 40,
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 20,
        right: 0,
        top: 250,
        bottom: 0,
      },
      signupbtn: {
        padding: 20,
        width: '90%',
        height: 40,
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 20,
        right: 0,
        top: 200,
        bottom: 0,
      },
      welcomenote: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 70,
        right: 0,
        top: 200,
        bottom: 0,
        width: '90%',
        height: 40,
        color: 'white',
      },
    });
```

Comment: i dont want image , iwant it to background image

Answer (score 2):

You have some problems:

1. alignItems: 'center,',  <- the comma inside ''
2. imageBackground component be the parent of view
3. remove height, left tops from 'loginbtn', 'signupbtn', etc

try use all flex css (that will be responsive); and don't use fixed height, or left or right or top

here the code working and tested:
[image]

```
import React from 'react';


import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground style={styles.backgroundContainer}
         source={{
           uri:
             'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524338198850-8a2ff63aaceb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=358&q=80',
         }}
      >
        <View style={styles.container}>

          <Text style={styles.welcomenote}>WELCOME TO ME</Text>
          <View style={styles.loginbtn}>
            <Button style={styles.loginbtn} title="LOGIN" />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.signupbtn}>
            <Button title="SIGNUP" />
          </View>

        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  backgroundContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  loginbtn: {
    padding: 20,
    width: '90%',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 250,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  signupbtn: {
    padding: 20,
    width: '90%',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 200,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  welcomenote: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 200,
    bottom: 0,
    width: '90%',
    height: 40,
    color: 'white',
  },
});
```

Comment: did you copy and pasted ? i've changed the code today, what do you see on your screen?, are you using last version react native?, you tried cancel, and npm start ?

Comment: bro, Can u suggest me a db, where i can integrate with react-native?

Comment: @sachinmurali please mark my answer like the right answer,  it's nice you lear postgress and mongodb,  both are needed ( relational database and no document db), but better to learn it with apollo graphql in client , and in server with  node, or golang

Comment: @sachinmurali please dont forget to click on the check my answer like the right, another people won't you answer when you get the answer but you mark like correct

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, ImageBackground, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={{
            uri:
              'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1524338198850-8a2ff63aaceb?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=358&q=80',
          }}
          style={styles.backgroundContainer}/>
          <Text style={styles.welcomenote}>WELCOME TO ME</Text>
          <View style={styles.loginbtn}>
            <Button style={styles.loginbtn} title="LOGIN" />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.signupbtn}>
            <Button title="SIGNUP" />
          </View>

      </View>
    );
  }
}
class DetailsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    Details: DetailsScreen,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  backgroundContainer: {
    width: 300,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height

  },
  loginbtn: {
    padding: 20,
    width: '90%',
    height: 40,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 20,
    right: 0,
    top: 250,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  signupbtn: {
    padding: 20,
    width: '90%',
    height: 40,
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 20,
    right: 0,
    top: 200,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  welcomenote: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 70,
    right: 0,
    top: 200,
    bottom: 0,
    width: '90%',
    height: 40,
  },
});
```

In the above as you are setting `height` of `backgroundContainer` to 100 it is taking only 100

Comment: if i set height to 100, then why it is not showing the image?

Comment: It is showing but only 100px in height not covering all the screen.

Comment: but i got an empty background??